# how to call just only data.addrow from database to google chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I got a Google Chart (column) that will call only the row from the database, and the column is defined by us. but I got a problem..the chart won't come out, can all of you see what is wrong with my source code..? thank u very much...!

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM grouppercent where idmember = '$idmembersession' and iddocument = '$iddoc'";
    $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
    {
        $subtitle = $row['subject'];
        echo "Title: " . $subtitle;
    }

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>SAM HISTOGRAM</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
function drawChart(json) 
{
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'SD-ESD');
        data.addColumn('string', 'WEHAB');
        data.addColumn('string', 'CROSS SECTORIAL');
        <?php
            foreach($row as $data)
             {
             echo "data.addRow( $data['resultsd'], $data['resultwe'], $data['resulttre'] );";
            }


        ?>
        var options = 
        {
            title: 'SAM Histogram Results',
            hAxis: {title: 'Sustainability Percentage'}, 
            titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'},
        } 

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        drawChart(data,options);  
}

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have 3 `string` type columns.  ColumnCharts allow the first column to be type `string`, but all other data series must be `number` type.  Second, your PHP code is not outputting valid javascript.  If you want to output strings, the strings need to be quoted in javascript, and your array references need to be enclosed in brackets so that PHP knows you are referencing `$data[key]` instead of outputting the value of `$data` followed by the string `'[key]'`.  This example assumes that you intend `$data['resultsd']` to be a string, and `$data['resultwe']` and `$data['resulttre']` to be numbers:

```
foreach($row as $data) {
    echo "data.addRow('{$data['resultsd']}', {$data['resultwe']}, {$data['resulttre']});";
}
```